# Can we cash a check under business name?

Tags: checking-account

My friend has 2 US Bank accounts.

One is under informal business names "Money Making" and the other is under personal name.

He's been trying to contact a person in USBank for several days via email but got no reply.

Finally on July 26th the one on Money Making is closed. He put some money there so he can withdraw to ATM.

He called another person in USBank. The other person allowed him to extend the closing of the remaining account to August 31st.

However, not much can be done on the closed account. A check has been made to payee "Money Making".

He asked that the money is deposited first on the main account but it can't be done anymore because the account is closed.

Now we have no idea how to cash a check addressed to "Money Making". Because there is no account with that name in this country. Also it's not save because if he can cash the check anyone can cash the check.

USBank doesn't seem to care and think it's closed we write a check and that's it.

Okay, what should we do?

Answer (score 3):

All banks in the US that I have ever worked with will allow you to deposit checks if:

1. A check is made out to you personally and you have an ID to prove that is you.
2. A business name if you have a business checking account in that name, which typically requires articles of incorporation or similar to prove the business entity.
3. A business alias if you have a registered DBA with your local jurisdiction.

In your case, you have 3 options:

1. Ask the issuer of the check to void it and reissue it made out to a different name.
2. Go to your "home" branch of the closed bank account and ask a manager to help you cash the check.
3. Last resort- reopen the account or another account with the same name. I think if you explain this possibility to the bank manager (option 2), they would hopefully see how asinine it would be for you to actually have to go through with this for a single check, and would just cash the check for you.

Comment: Your issue will be convince the manager of your 'home' branch that 'Money Maker' is really you. If he just says "Oh, what the heck I'll cash it" and it turns out the cheque wasn't intended for you he'll lose his job, or worse.

Comment: @DJClayworth - The business account would still have a person associated with it, he should be able to just show his ID. He could also bring the same documentation he used when he opened the account under that name.

Comment: The account is opened 20 years ago on a name. At first he thought that he should register LLC but turns out USBank allows opening account under any name. That's 20 years ago. Now USbank closed the account, and then

Comment: @JimThio: What is the reason they gave you for closing the account?

Comment: Using indonesian mailing list.